# Is there a way to know who executed a command?

Tags: rhel, rm, history

we are using redhat and we would to know if there is a way to show the session id or username who executes a rm command line, recently, someone from other teams delete a .jar file and me and my team wants to know who is ?
there is a way to know without installing any other software ?

Comment: Ask them who it was? This seems to be a social problem, not a technical one.

Comment: search their shell history file

Comment: What were the permissions of the file and the directory that contained it? Can anyone delete it? Do you know that time the file was deleted?

Comment: @Kusalananda as someone who works in a large corporate with many employees, I can related to this question. Some servers are shared by many different users from many different teams, and you don't even know everyone. Not to mention that sometimes people do things inadvertently without even noticing it. The person who deleted the file might not be even aware of them.

Comment: @aviro As someone in the same kind of workplace, asking "Who did this?" rarely benefits the quality of future work. Instead, asking "How can we sort out the issue with this file disappearing?" would be more conducive to actually moving forward. Rather than assigning blame, it's better to look to the future, resolve the issue and work with the other team to set up routines that make it less likely to happen again.

Comment: To complete @Kusalananda 's comment, this means applying the principle of least privilege, separate accounts for every team member, backups, and a versioning system.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into the shell history file (`.bash_history` if you're using Bash) of each one of your team members to see if you find the offending command, provided they haven't covered their traces by deleting it.

If the user has run `sudo` beforehand *and* you have sudo logging enabled, you can look in `/var/log/sudo` for the offending command and user.

If everybody knows the root password (bad!) and the culprit ran the offending command as root, there's no way to know. Even installing some software after the fact won't be of any help; audit tools must be set up beforehand.